# Sending to production or review environments depending on branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We're using Gitlab-CI but we have some troubles to have review and production environments at the same time.

We have several stages in our `.gitlab-ci.yml` but here I'll focus on the deploy stage:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - some commands
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    url: http://$CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG.$DEPLOY_SERVER
    on_stop: stop_deploy
  only:
    - /^feature-[cw]\/.*$/

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - some other commands
  environment:
    name: production
  only:
    - prod


stop_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - some clean commands
  when: manual
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    action: stop
  only:
    - /^feature-[cw]\/.*$/
```

The issue is that the first job is not run on the branches whose name starts with `feature-c/`. However when removing the second job, the first job is run on those branches.

The job that deploys to production is correctly run when pushed to `prod`.

So why does the first job is not run when the second job is defined? Where does the conflict comes from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is quite simple; they can't have the same name :) Name one deploy-review and the other deploy-prod and its fixed.

Comment: Obviously… that was so stupid. That's the danger of copying/pasting.Thanks!